# ArgumentNullException was unhandled What is wrong?

Tags: c#, xml, xna, xml-serialization

I have written a class to load an XML file but I always get this error message:

ArgumentNullException was unhandled
This method does not accept null for this parameter.
Parameter name: texture

I get the error message in the batch.Draw():

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch batch)
{
        batch.Draw(
                texture,
                position,
                null,
                Color.White,
                rotation,
                Vector2.Zero,
                scale,
                SpriteEffects.None,
                0f);
        }
```

What is wrong in the Sprite class?
I uploaded my project here: http://depositfiles.com/files/kj4an4ef7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, like the error says, the variable `texture` in the `Sprite` drawing code is null.

The cause of the problem is: you call the `Load()` method to load the list of sprites from the XML file, but that won't reconstruct the `Texture` property of the `Sprite` class. Thus, to fix your error, for each sprite you should call the `Load()` too.

That means, in the `LoadContent()` method of the `Game1` class, after the `sprites = Content.Load<List<Sprite>>("Levelinf");` line, do something like this:

```
foreach(Sprite sprite in sprites) {
    sprite.Load(Content);
}
```

Now, each sprite will have it's texture loaded.

PS: this is more like a C# /XNA problem rather than a XML one :)